# how to use sls with get-azlocation in Azure (Powershell)

Tags: azure, powershell

a simple question:

Why this piece of powershell is not working:

```
Get-AzLocation | ft  | sls europe
```

When i use sls with file output there is no problem:

```
Get-AzLocation |ft > test.txt
cat .\test.txt | sls europe
```

How to make it work in 1 line w/o dumping content to a file?

Comment: IMO there is no need to revert to text output (insert `|Out-String`) if you can treat objects with `Where-Object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment mentioned, you could use `Where-Object`.

```
Get-AzLocation | Where-Object {$_.Location -like '*europe*'} | ft
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Also shorter version is working - Get-AzLocation | Where-Object Location -like "\*europe\*" | ft

Comment: **NEED TO LOGIN TO AZURE ACCOUNT FIRST**